# How to create a matrix from product of all elements in two arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, product, multiplication

I was reading the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html#bu900n6) for matlab on element-wise multiplication and I came across this example:

> Create a row vector a and a column vector b, then multiply them. The
>   1-by-3 row vector and 6-by-1 column vector combine to produce a 6-by-3
>   matrix with all combinations of elements multiplied.

The documentation sure showed the output, but how did they get to that output matrix of size`6,3`? Which was obtained from multiplying a column vector `b` of size `6,1`, and a row vector `a` of size `1,3` using the methods explained in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called broadcasting. When one dimension is 1 while the other is bigger, the unit dimension is expanded, as if with `repmat`:

```
 6 1 : column
 1 3 : row
 ------
 6 3 : result
```

Given

```
a = 1:3
b = [1:6]'
a .* b
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
a2 = repmat(a, 6, 1)
b2 = repmat(b, 1, 3)
a2 .* b2
```

But of course broadcasting is much more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I took a long break from Matlab (>5 years), just getting back into it. Fixed the answer.

Comment: They might call it [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/); anyhow, it also works for plus/mins like NumPy's broadcasting feature